# Soap response with stripped end tag

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have iPhone app that worked fine with SOAP and WSDL untill today. It suddenly started sending SOAP response with stripped end tag. for example

```
...../SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelop
```

instead of

```
..../SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Nothing have been changed from server. Any idea why i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

After spending 3 hours i got solution. Thought to share here if somebody else get this sort of problem.

It was due to weired characters. Windows automatically put some characters into soap file. So when it return response it counts no. of characters but because there are hidden BOM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark characters so it included them and sends actual response stripped.

So just find BOM and remove them and you will be fine

Thanks